# Fortran write array tab delimited to text file

Tags: formatting, fortran

Is there a way to write an array in one line (without do-loop) (in fortran) and have it being tab-delimited?

I have tried the following two versions without success.. (the first writes just one number and the second writes them all padding with spaces)

```
real       :: var(10)
var = 1
write(*,'(10(t1,f7.2))')
write(*,'(t1,10f7.2)')
```

I have looked [here](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap05/format.html) without finding out howto. (although it gave some info).

Comment: There are ways to do what you want (and someone with time may write an answer or find another link), but I'll note that the "tabbing" that comes with the `T` edit descriptor has nothing to do with ASCII tab characters.  You can add the latter as text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
real :: var(10)
var=1
write(*,"(10(f7.2,a))") (var(i),achar(9),i=1,10)
```

Comment: Or if your compiler supports the F2008 unlimited repeat count feature:
`real :: var(10)
var = 1.
write (*,"(*(f7.2,:,a))") (var(i),achar(9),i=1,size(var))`

Note the colon - this prevents a trailing tab. (That's a F77 feature.)

Can't see how to get a line break in that code!

Comment: @steve Just in retirement and already working on stackoverflow anyway ?

Comment: Sorry Steve but I don't understand how you could avoid the last tab with ":" ; for me, this works only for elements within the format itself. But achar(9) belongs to the variables being written => 10 tabs are expected !

Comment: Maybe to avoid the last tab : character(20) :: form ; form="(999(f7.2,:,'"//achar(9)//"'))" ; write(*,form) var

Comment: @FrancoisJacq not retired yet - but soon. You're right that the last tab would not be avoided with the code I gave, but it really shouldn't matter.

Comment: `write(*,"(9(f7.2,a),f7.2)") (var(i),achar(9),i=1,9), var(10)` should be ok to avoid the last tab.

Comment: @FrancoisJacq: why not simply `write(*,'(f7.2,9("'//achar(9)//'",f7.2))',var(1:10))`? Is this kind of coding deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

The original answer is 100% correct for the question, but a more generic answer I made based on a csv format string Steve Lionel gave on the Intel Fortran forums (I can't seem to find that post right now) is the following:

```
tsvFormat = '(*(G0.6,:,"'//achar(9)//'"))'
write(*, tsvFormat) ValueArr, moreRealValues, 64.0, maybeAnIntegerArrayToo, string
```